# Send string to python script through server

Tags: python, shell, scripting

How could I send a string(shell script file name) from an android app to a python program on my pc, and have python execute the script named in said string?

I have the python script done... doThis(./openNetflix) will run the ./openNetflix script, which as you probably guessed opens Netflix.

How do I configure a python server to recieve a string and pass it to my doThis(scriptNameString) function?

Comment: Easiest way to do it would be with REST interface as there are ready libs for it, for example bottle http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html

Comment: Does it need to be Python? You could do this with a one-liner shell script around netcat… Or, even more simply, this is exactly what telnet, rsh, etc. already do…

Comment: As an aside, you should be very careful if you are planning to set up a server that accepts any string and executes it. There are many malicious ways to explit that. (e.g. someone sending "rm -rf /" to the server). Even if your server is in a secure/isolated network, it would still be good practice to make sure the server can only do 'known'/'good' things. E.g. have a list of commands its allowed to run.

Comment: @abarnert Yes! :D just a personal project I decided to use as many languages as possible just for learning purposes. Python being one of them.

Comment: @Puciek id upvote for the insanely quick reply but I am unable as of yet.

Comment: Don't worry about it, if I were here for points this would be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: @TomDalton Excellent point, thanks. Security was something I  planned on learning more about through this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started writing a bit lengthy comment on this case, but when you are approaching chars limit for a comment it's good to convert it into an answer I guess!

Easiest way to do this task would be with one of many excellent python libraries for creating REST services. My personal favourite is [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), and implementing this type of service in with bottle would be as simple as:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/execute/<command>')
def execute(command):
    if command == "list_blogs":
        // Do something 1
    elif command == "format_c":
        // Do something 2

run(host='localhost', port=79897)
```

This will not only provide you with the REST service, but will also put a iron wall between user input and actual execution, so the user input will not get mangled with the file you are trying to execute. Just remember to never use command variable anywhere outside of the if/else.

As you can notice this comes with a weakness - anyone with this link can call those functions and potentially cause denial of service, or maybe even actual damage. This is why it would be nice to have some sort of control and added security, to know that the request was made from valid client.
There are many ways to tackle this issue, i strongly encourage you to have a deeper look into those available. Very simple one would be to store on your server a dict of keys and salts, like that:

```
salts["here_you_put_random_hash_as_key"] = "and_here_the_salt"
```

And then you also store the salt and key for this specific client in the clients code. Then when client makes a request he includes his key and a checksum (which consists of md5 made from the command, clients salt key and, for example, current hour) as additional arguments. Then when you receive the request and all 3 variables, you try to create your own checksum using same data (so you pick the salt for client key provided and calculate md5 for that salt, current hour and command coming from the client) and if they match then you know that the request is valid.

Comment: Very cool. Exactly what I needed. Thank you, you complete whacko!